# Express - get user's ip family

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there some property on `req` object to get ip's family (IPv4 or IPv6)? Or how can I figure it out? I want to change behavior based on this info. I'm not sure if checking if the string contains a colon is the right way.

Comment: Try `req.client.remoteFamily`.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I logged both `req.ip` and `req.client.remoteFamily`: `IPv6 172.xx.xx.xx`, which doesn't look true. I should mention I use a reverse proxy (ngrok). Logged ip is mine (I set trust proxy).

Comment: @SviatozarPetrenko so the client connected to ngrok using IPv6, and ngrok connected to your server using IPv4?

Comment: @robertklep I guess vice versa. I am connected to ngrok with my ip being v4 (it was logged). Ngrok is connected to server through localhost, which (if I remember correctly) was in v6 format (before I set trust proxy 'loopback'). I guess `req.client.remoteFamily` doesn't care about `trust proxy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in [net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) package for this:

- [`net.isIPv4(input)`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#netisipv4input)
- [`net.isIPv6(input)`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#netisipv6input)

You also have [`net.isIP(input)`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#netisipinput) which will return `6`, `4` or `0` if the parameter is respectively an IPv6, an IPv4, or not an IP.